# Get image name,resolution,path,extension and fileszie

Tags: php

I have been working and am not being able to get any solution.I have a folder named "download" which contain several images, my task is to echo all the images and  display next to it, the corresponding image name,path resolution,extension and filesize.Can someone help ?

I have been able to display all the images..

path where the images are stored is "C:\xampp\htdocs\2in1 file\download"

here is my code:

```
<?php

$files = glob("download/*.*");
echo"<table border=1>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Preview";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Name";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Extension";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Resolution";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"File Size";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Path";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
$image = $files[$i];

echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" width="100px" height="100px" />';
echo"</td>";


  }
 echo"</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked php GD and image functions? http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help

```
<?php

    $files = glob("download/*.*");
    echo"<table border=1>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $path = pathinfo($image);
        $name = $path['filename'];
        $ext = $path['extension'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
        $resolution = $width . ' x ' . $height . ' Pexel';
        $path = $path['dirname'];
        $size = filesize($image);

        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" width="100px" height="100px" />';
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo $name;
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo $ext;
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo $resolution;
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo $size . ' Byte';
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo $path;
        echo"</td>";
    }
    echo"</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I was doing the same thing but in a different way but yours is better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)" for resolution, "[filesize](http://fr.php.net/filesize)" for the image size, "[realpath](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.realpath.php)" for an absolute path and "[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)" for filename, path, extension, etc.

Example :

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $info = pathinfo($image);
    $resolution = getimagesize($image);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" width="100px" height="100px" />';
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $info['filename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $info['extension'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . strval($resolution[0]) . "x" . strval($resolution[1]) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . strval(filesize($image)) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . realpath($image) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/getimagesize). Or [exif_read_data](https://www.php.net/exif_read_data) for more information about jpeg/tiff-files.

Use [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.pathinfo.php) to get info about extension and path:

```
$info = pathinfo(__DIR__ . '/download/' . $image);
var_dump($info);
```

Comment: @Johnson Smith added example

Answer (score 0):

`getimagesize()` — Get the size of an image

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

    $info = pathinfo($files[$i]);

    //only deal with images
    if(in_array(strtolower($info['extension']), array("jpg", "png", "gif", "svg"))){
        $image = $files[$i];

        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" width="100px" height="100px" />';
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td>".$info['filename']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$info['extension']."</td>";
        echo "<td>$width x $height</td>";
        echo "<td>".filesize($image)." bytes</td>";
        echo "<td>$image</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems good but when am trying this code nothing is displayed..I understood the logic behind your code and now am using the logic to do my task :)

Comment: what file extensions do your images have? Is it ".jpeg" or ".bmp" or something else that isn't in the array of "accepted filetypes" you will have too add them. I also added strtolower (a function that makes the extension lowercase all times)

Comment: then it should work now? With `strtolower($info['extension'])` added